# Communicating two Android phones with no internet and then synchronize

Tags: android, one-to-many, communication

I'm building one application built for people that works where there is no internet, normally some employees need to ask permissions for their boss. The application will be doing many things, for example, trying to connect with the boss to ask something.

We have talked about how to solve this.

We are going to have a public server listening for this permissions from one phone an send it to another phone. They can be very far away.

So If the phone don't have internet it will try to save the information and then send it again when he is in the city.

At that time the server is going to receive the request and save this request in a little database. This user will be needed to ask the server it he has some information. The server will send the information.

Is a kind of normal problem, what I want to know is what does Android has to help up to this easier. I have read many things but they don't work because the -lacking of internet-. I thing this lacking is very inusual actually.

I suppose that there has to be something for solving this kind of problems, we can use Services, TCP, Messages. But anybody is managing the out of Internet service, we can be more than 6 hours without internet.

**Even we prefer if we don't need the server, maybe their two connections can be available with out the server.**

We would prefer to use only telephones, is that possible ?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I propose you to:
1) save each "NoInternet" Android message inside a SQLite Db.(id,message,create_at)

2) create an Android Service which main goal is to send "NoInternet" message

3) create and Android BroadcastReceiver which Listen for Network connexion and trig the Service for POST all saved "NoINternet" Message.

i hope that can help you. ;-)

Comment: Hello, how can I use a Service and what is an BroadcastReceiver. It is important to us to don´t use many memory. Regards,

Comment: A Android BroadcastReceiver is an Object which are able to listen for some Systems events as network_connexion, system_boot, sms_receiv, screen_on, screen_of...etc, I can just recomand you to search for how to use an Android Service and how to use Android BroadcastReceiver on Google search, explain it here can take many line, sorry...:-(

Comment: Ps, look for IntentService. at:  https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use Parse.com as your database.  It will handle saving to the internet when a connection becomes available.  Each phone can pull the latest data at appropriate times, or you can send push messages.

Comment: ORMLite on the device, right?  That wouldn't preclude using parse.com as your cloud communication / storage system.  Depending on your requirements that may also mean you don't need to operate a server at all.  I'm not saying it's the only option - GCM would seem like a good solution too.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into GCM (Google Cloud Messaging).  GCM will hold messages to a device for a specified length of time (up to 4 weeks) if the device is not on the Internet.  I don't know about what happens if you try to send an upstream message (from device to server) if you don't have an Internet connection.

Comment: In this case it is our server that will be used here. We have already a server. Regards,